# Android ViewPager2, Webview, fullscreen and touch events

Tags: android, webview, android-touch-event, android-viewpager2

I'm trying to do a proof of concept where a Webview loads local HTML files and users are able to swipe left/right to go to the next file, all while in fullscreen.  I'm utilizing ViewPager2 and normal Webviews.  I have that part working, but what I want to do is, upon the user doing a single tap, show or hide the toolbar, status bar and navigation controls.  Right now I have the setOnTouchListener code on the viewPager, but it looks like the touch events are being consumed by the webview.

How can I accomplish where a single tap would do a toggle between fullscreen and non-fullscreen mode, without disrupting ViewPager paging and long press in the webview?

Here is most of my code.  I'm leaving parts out for brevity that should not be related.

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        viewPager.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            when(event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    initialX = event.rawX
                    initialY = event.rawY
                    moved = false
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    if (event.rawX != initialX || event.rawY != initialY) {
                        moved = true
                    }
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    if (!moved) {
                        toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
            true
        }

        viewPager.adapter = MyAdapter(items, this)
    }
}
```

```
class MyAdapter(private val items: List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, parent, false) as WebView
        return MyViewHolder(view, items)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }
}

class MyViewHolder (private val webView: WebView, private val items: List<String>) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(webView) {
    internal fun bind(position: Int) {
        webView.loadUrl("file://" + items[position])
    }
}
```